# How do I call my dict parameters from the view.py render in my template?

Tags: django, templates, dictionary, view, parameters

I have been working on this for two day, and have read almost every example on stackoverflow and consulted the django documentation.  I am trying to pass my dict from the views.py to my template, but I keep getting the stupid "Could not parse the remainder" error.  I'm not doing anything fancy.  Just Href buttons passing in a parameter to represent what that button is.  Then a template page opens using that parameter as a string to make the new page and url unique.

pass in with:

```
<a href="{% url 'site:call' 1 %}" class="btn">Call</a>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^call=(\d+)/$', views.call, name='call')
]
```

views.py

```
def call(request, callID):
    call_id = { 'id':callID }
    return render(request, 'site/call.html', call_id)
```

Call template

```
{% extends 'site/layout.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% with call_id.get('id') as view_id %}
<h3 class="center-align blue lighten-3">Site # Room {{ view_id }}</h3>
<a href="/site/cancel.html" class="btn">Cancel</a>
{% endwith %}

{% endblock %}
```

I have tried request.GET.get('id') and a bizillion other things.  Can someone show me how I can actually parse those dict values I passed in?

Comment: Did you try reading the actual [template documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/language/#variables), which is quite explicit about how to do this? Or searching SO for the many previous questions that quote that exact error message?

Comment: Although it's far from clear why you're using a dict at all, rather than passing the id directly.

Comment: I am using the render function, and it said to use context, which was redacted, so the documentation said use dict.

Comment: also the variable section covers dict, and I was able to not get the parse error, but the browser froze the rendering after the title from my index page.  I think the for loop looped indefinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually passing a dictionary at all. You're passing a single value, `id`, so you should just use that. And there is no need for any `with` block.

```
Site # Room {{ id }}
```

Comment: YOU ARE THE BEST!!  Thank you sir!